# Should we have a biology, anatomy or physiology type tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have a biology, anatomy or physiology type tag?

To give a few examples:

The answer to this is concerned with the rabbits physiology:
[Do bunnies eat their droppings?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/617/do-bunnies-eat-their-droppings)
The asnwers to these are concerned with the animals anatomy:
[Why do cats often screech when mating?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/933/why-do-cats-often-screech-when-mating)
[Why do my dogs stand back to back when they mate?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/932/why-do-dogs-stand-back-to-back-when-they-mate)

Should we have a [biology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) to cover actual physiological or anatomical facts about pets?

Answer (score 1):

My inclination is yes - there are times when knowing their pet's anatomy/biology/physiology can be important (such as dog breeds that are prone to ear infections because they have long ear canals and floppy ears, cat breeds like the Persians with their very compressed sinuses and the associated issues there - just to name a few)

There's also the questions that arise from pet behavior, like the question a while back about the Flehmen response.

Answer (score 1):

I see [biology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) and [breeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breeding) existing hand in hand in many cases, but I do see clear cases where they'd appear independently. A question about Dachshunds being prone to back problems and paralysis would definitely fall into [biology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) and not really [breeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breeding) - so I see no reason for both not to exist.

Watch out for a 'genetic' sort of tag to appear, because that's probably *always* going to mean [biology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) when it comes to the scope of this site. I'm not one for preemptive synonyms, but *that* particular one might make sense.

Comment: So you are in favor of biology and synonymised breeding to biology or kill breeding?

Comment: @Skippy I think both tags would work, actually - while breeding implies biology, biology doesn't _always_ imply breeding.